# How to recursively remove different files in two directories

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 different recursive directories, in one directory have 200 **.txt** files in another have 210 **.txt** files, need a script to find the different file names and remove them from the directory.

Comment: `ls dir1 > d1f.txt ; l2 dir2 > d2f.txt`. Write in your favorite language the script that removes similar lines of 2 files and do `rm $(cat ./diff.txt)`. There's no need spent hours on a single bash script when you can do it with stuff you know.

Comment: have a look at `find`, `grep`,`sort`,`comm`, `rm` and you should be able to do it.

Comment: I have to do this every one hour interval, so if I got a script for remove the different file, I will do this by cron for every one hour.

Comment: Are the files different for you if they have the same name, but are in different subdirectories?

Comment: This question is currently cross-posted on Unix+Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223141/how-to-remove-a-different-files-in-two-recursive-directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably better ways, but I think about:

```
find directory1 directory2 -name \*.txt -printf '%f\n' |
  sort | uniq -u |
  xargs -I{} find directory1 directory2 -name {} -delete
```

`find directory1 directory2 -name \*.txt -printf '%f\n'`:
  print basename of each file matching the glob `*.txt`

`sort | uniq -u`:
  only print unique lines (if you wanted to delete duplicate, it would have been `uniq -d`)

`xargs -I{} find directory1 directory2 -name {} -delete`:
  remove them (re-specify the path to narrow the search and avoid deleting files outside the initial search path)

### Notes

Thank's to @KlausPrinoth for all the suggestions.

Obviously I'm assuming a GNU userland, I suppose people running with the tools providing bare minimum POSIX compatibility will be able to adapt it.

Comment: Have a look at `uniq`'s `-u` option too, to avoid `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way is to use `diff` which is more than capable in finding file differences in files in directories. For instance if you have `d1` and `d2` that contain your 200 and 210 files respectively (with the first 200 files being the same), you could use `diff` and `process substitution` to provide the names to remove to a while loop:

```
( while read -r line; do printf "rm %s\n" ${line##*: }; done < <(diff -q d1 d2) )
```

**Output (of d1 with 10 files, d2 with 12 files)**

```
rm file11.txt
rm file12.txt
```

`diff` will not fit all circumstances, but is does a great job finding directory differences and is quite flexible.

Comment: Shouldn't here be used `comm` instead of `diff` to handle missing lines correctly?

Comment: No, `comm` would require the use of a temporary file because it is designed to operate 'line-by-line' on the **contents** of files themselves, not on the contents of directories.

Comment: Klaus, it also by default compares the contents of ***directories***. `comm` doesn't. `man 1 diff: FILES  are  'FILE1 FILE2' or 'DIR1 DIR2'`.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that. It's described sparely to compare directories in the man page.